# Using semaphore for sync firebase query in Swift 4

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, semaphore

I'm trying to use a semaphore to have the code wait for the firebase query results.

The code is the following:

```
var valor: Decimal = 0
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
//procedimenton para leitura dos dados no Firebase e jogar no array
Constants.refs.databaseRoot.child("Lancamentos").queryOrdered(byChild: "ContaDebito").queryEqual(toValue: "1.1.6").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
        for snap in snapshots {
            if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                let post = FIRLancamento()
                post.setValuesForKeys(postDict)
                    let credito = post.Valor
                    valor += Decimal(string: credito)!
                print (credito + " " + String(describing: valor))

            }
        }
        semaphore.signal()
    }

})
semaphore.wait()
print(valor)
```

When I run this code, the semaphore signal never gets triggered and the program stays frozen, and I see the following error in the console:

```
2017-10-26 16:55:23.830048-0400 BVI_Swift[10830:1929792] TIC TCP Conn Failed [1:0x604000169a80]: 3:-9802 Err(-9802)
2017-10-26 16:55:23.831266-0400 BVI_Swift[10830:1929792] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
2017-10-26 16:55:23.831597-0400 BVI_Swift[10830:1929792] Task . HTTP load failed (error code: -1200 [3:-9802])
2017-10-26 16:55:23.832476-0400 BVI_Swift[10830:1929780] Task . finished with error - code: -1200
```

If I comment the `semaphore.wait()` line, the query works perfeclty, but the `print(valor)` line is executed before it has any values.

Comment: did you find a solution to this yet??

Answer (score 0):

Do you block main thread when you do this?
As an example; if run this block inside button selector function and do not return; all application will freeze so `semaphore.signal()` will never executed.

Try running that block like this:

```
func buttonClick() {
   DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
      // your sync firebase operation
      // ...
   }
}
```